# Select rows having only one value in certain column

Tags: mysql, where-clause, having

I have a list of items in a table and I want to select only some of them:
Here's my table:

```
CREATE TABLE conexiones(
    idCon int not null,
    idType int not null
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**And here are the conexiones items:**

```
INSERT INTO conexiones (idCon,idType) VALUES
(1,1),
(2,1),
(3,1),
(4,1),
(5,1),
(6,1),
(2,2),
(3,2),
(4,2);
```

**What I have is this set of results:**

| idCon | idType |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 |
| 6 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 |

### What I need:

To show all items that do not share the same idCon, while having different idType.

### Example 1 of expected result:

Show only items with idType 1, but eliminate the item that has idType of 1 and does share an idCon with idType 2, so the expected result would be:

| idCon | idType |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 |
| 6 | 1 |

### Example 2 of expected result:

Show only items with idType 2, but eliminate any item that has idType of 2 and does share an idCon with idType 1, so the expected result would be:

| idCon | idType |
| --- | --- |
| no results |  |

**How should I achieve that?**

Comment: can you clarify why the idCon 3 and 5 where not skipped from result but 4 was skipped in expected result 1 !

Comment: Hi @HarshGundecha, because idCon 3 and 5 do not have idType 2

Comment: my bad 5 doesn't have but i can see 3 do have idType 2, update: updated question seems to make sense

Comment: You are right!! Thanks! I corrected the mistake. :) Number 3 should not be on the list either.

Comment: idCon 2 would also not be there in output i think

Comment: You're right again! Thanks! I corrected the mistake!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can do it.

```
select * from conexiones
 where idType = 1 -- Show only items with idType 1
    and idCon not in ( -- eliminating the item that has idType of 1 and does share an idCon with idType 2
        select idCon from conexiones where idType=2
    );
    
select * from conexiones
 where idType = 2
    and idCon not in (select idCon from conexiones where idType=1);
```

working demo -> https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sYajoTcAbEPVdVxSNYfSJ2/0

Answer (score 1):

Is not your Example 1 wrong ?
Shouldn't it be like that :

| idCon | idType |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 |
| 6 | 1 |

Example 1 :

```sql
SELECT idCon, idType
FROM conexiones
WHERE idCon NOT IN (SELECT idCon FROM conexiones WHERE idType=2)
AND idType=1;
```

Example 2 :

```sql
SELECT idCon, idType
FROM conexiones
WHERE idCon NOT IN (SELECT idCon FROM conexiones WHERE idType=1)
AND idType=2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Below possible solution:

```
select distinct idCon, min(idType) idType
from conexiones group by idCon
having count(distinct idType) = 1
```

[SQL fiddle](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=93b8dc5b1e0963806aadf0a78f3553c4&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql80)

Using above single query we can select all items have single idType (1 and 2)